# How to get certain elements of an array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to fetch data coming from a request, I used PostMan to send the request. the following arrays are the output of **dd($items);** ... The data that I want from these arrays are the **id** and **quantity**

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:12 [
    "id" => 4
    "name" => "omnis"
    "image_name" => "https://source.unsplash.com/random"
    "description" => "Officiis ea provident eius perspiciatis provident et eveniet illo. Tempore ullam ab molestiae unde. Fugit pariatur consequatur sunt veritatis. Laudantium quos veritatis quasi dolorum."
    "price" => 9
    "discount" => 0
    "status" => 1
    "category_id" => 24
    "place_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2019-12-15 08:05:36"
    "updated_at" => "2019-12-15 08:05:36"
    "quantity" => 5
  ]
  1 => array:12 [
    "id" => 5
    "name" => "molestiae"
    "image_name" => "https://source.unsplash.com/random"
    "description" => "Debitis dignissimos est veritatis veritatis sit. Ut ex non nam aliquid dolore vero earum. Ab aliquid et quibusdam enim."
    "price" => 7
    "discount" => 0
    "status" => 1
    "category_id" => 25
    "place_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2019-12-15 08:05:36"
    "updated_at" => "2019-12-15 08:05:36"
    "quantity" => 3
  ]
]
```

I want to do foreach loop to get this:

```
{
  "id":4,
  "quantity":5
},
{
  "id":5,
  "quantity":3
}
```

It tried :

```
       $item_array = [];
        foreach ($items as $key=>$item)
        {
            $item_array[$key] = $item['id'];
            $item_array[$key] = $item['quantity'];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The data that I want from these arrays are the id and quantity

that is:

```php
       $item_array = [];
       foreach ($items as $item) {
          $item_array[] = [
             'id' => $item['id'],
             'quantity' => $item['quantity']
          ];
       }
```

or if you'd like to use true Laravel way:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$result = array_map(
  function($x) { 
    return Arr::only($x, ['id', 'quantity']); 
  }, 
  $source
);
```

or collect($source)->map(...) to utilize collection instead of array.

Comment: Yep. :) Updated again. Frankly speaking, the first version was okay but not clear what the source is. Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop into

```
foreach ($items as $key=>$item)
{
    $item_array[$key] = array(
     'id' => $item['id'],
     'quantity' => $item['quantity']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do it like this:

```
 $item_array = [];
    foreach ($items as $key=>$item)
    {
        $obj = (object) ["id"=>$item['id'],"quantity"=>$item['quantity']];
        $item_array[$key]=$obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

collect($items)->map(function($item) {
    return Arr::only($item, ['id', 'quantity']);
})->all();
```

Comment: It should work with a note: the result is a collection, and NOT an array. It can or con not make sense depending on context. As for response()->json($result) it should work like a charm :)

Comment: @artoodetoo the `all` method call is what returns it as an array, so it isn't a collection

Comment: The whole set is a collection of arrays. I meant it. But again, it is probably not a problem.

Comment: @artoodetoo it is array. see:https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-all

Comment: @TsaiKoga you're right. I was inattentive. all() method turns a collection back into an array.   